# bash sort numerically correct

Tags: bash, sorting

I'm having a problem with sorting that `-V` isn't solving. I have a very well structured set of folder names (shown below with `sort -V`) that I want to do a version sort but recognizing floating point numbers (see the first two entries). Any advice?

```
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_3_um_V_97.4_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_3_um_V_97_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_6_um_V_90_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_6_um_V_153_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_7_um_V_70_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_8_um_V_70_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_8_um_V_80_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_9_um_V_192_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_10_um_V_90_V
```

Comment: How is this a bash issue?  I don't see any code in the question.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "do a version sort but recognizing floating point numbers?" A version sort is a version sort precisely because it interprets fields with dots in a different way than floating point numbers. If you just want to do a lexicographic sort by field where some of the fields are numeric, use `_` as the delimiter and specify the `g` modifier on appropriate fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply numeric sort for 15th field if you want to sort by floating point number.

```
$ cat test.txt | sort -t _ -V -k 1,14 -k 15n 
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_3_um_V_97_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_3_um_V_97.4_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_6_um_V_90_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_6_um_V_153_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_7_um_V_70_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_8_um_V_70_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_8_um_V_80_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_9_um_V_192_V
Xe_phi_3.5_eV_tOn_0.5_ns_tOff_20_ns_d_10_um_V_90_V
```